# If there is $U^TAU=I$, show that $A$ is symmetric positive definite.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Let $A$ and $U$ be $n \times n$ matrices. If there is $U^TAU=I$ (where $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix), show that $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix.

Comment: Try expressing $A$ in terms of $U$ (and functions of $U$). Do some work.

Comment: Thanks. Then, I need to prove that $U$ is invertible first.

Comment: If the product of square matrices is invertible then...

Comment: @Evans $[U^TA]U = I$, so $U^TA$ must be the inverse of $U$.

Comment: Thanks! I gave proof by showing that the columns of $U$ are linearly independent. I believe that your method is much easier and clearer! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $I$ is invertible, so is every matrix on the RHS. Let $V = U^{-1}$. Then $A=V^t V.$ This is positive definite, because $<Ax, x> = <Vx, Vx>= \|Vx\| > 0.$

Comment: @TeresaLisbon There was already an answer, which hurt my aesthetic sense.

Comment: Sorry about that. I hold myself accountable here.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U = \{u_1, u_2, ..., u_n\}$.

Consider $\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iu_i=0$, there is $<\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iu_i, Au_j>=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i<u_i, Au_j>=\lambda_j<u_j, Au_j>=\lambda_j=0$.

Therefore, $\{u_1, u_2, ..., u_n\}$ forms a basis for $\mathbf{R}^n$.

Then, $U$ is invertible.

Thus $A=(U^T)^{-1}U^{-1}=(U^{-1})^TU^{-1}$, which implies that $A$ is a symmertic positive definite matrix.